# How to create Float status displays like this in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, layout

So i've been learning Android Development and was curious how to create this using Fragments.

[image: screenshot]

It doesn't need to be exactly like this, i'm referring to how they are displaying a text next to the image like that but not having the fragment not occupy the whole screen.

Would each textview/image view pair be a fragment?

Any discussion is great, i'm trying to move past the linear thinking of having only fragments being squares and whatnot

Comment: You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) for this, if you have anything that you have done so far share it so we can help you. it is hard helping you any code that you wrote.

Comment: I'm happy to just discuss concepts, the implementation shouldn't be too bad. So you would link each pair together constraint wise.

Comment: *I'm happy to just discuss concepts*, that's good to hear but stack overflow is not the site for it. Here you can find [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)